# Using Azure Data Sync between databases at different Azure datacenters

Tags: azure, azure-data-sync

We are looking to host our Azure web application at 2-3 locations globally to reduce load latency and for BCP if an application server fails (we will use Traffic Manager to direct traffic)

We will be co-locating the Azure SQL DB databases along with the web app. We want to get the databases synced near real-time. The data volumes will be under 1 GB on any given day. There will be no on-premise database. Here intent is not to have a master slave but more active-active databases

Given Azure Data Sync is now in GA,

a) What kind of delay in sync should I plan for (I can tolerate a few seconds of latency)

b) Will there be any performance issues in both the DB's during these periods of sync. How do conflicts get resolved- latest timestamp?

c)  Can I use out of-the-box azure portal functionality- or will I need additional tools

Answer (score 1):

Minimum sync frequency is 5 minutes. 
Check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data